# Display only first-child/top-level subcategories in archive product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display only first child subcategories in my theme, so I've edited archive-product.php like this:

```
// The product category taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';

// Get the parent categories IDs
$parent_cat_ids = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'fields'     => 'ids'
) );

// Get only "child" WP_Term Product categories
$subcategories = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'exclude'     => $parent_cat_ids,
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'asc',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

if( ! empty( $subcategories ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo '<li>
            <a href="'. get_term_link($subcategory) .'" >' . $subcategory->name.'</a>
        </li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It's now generating the list, But it returns all categories and subcategories. I just want to show the subcategories of currently viewing category (first childs only). How can I achieve this?
For example:

```
Category 1
Category 2
    Sub Category of 2
    Sub Category of 2
Category 3
    Sub Category of 3
Category 4
    Sub category of 4
```

I want Category 1,2,3 and 4 which are sub categories of currently browsing category. Not their sub categories.

Comment: How can access to current category id? Isset into $_GET ?

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh this code goes to archive-product.php of current theme, So it knows which category we are talking about.

Comment: Why don't get subcategories with set parent options in get_terms function?

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh how you mean?

Answer (score -1):

If you add the shortcode `[product_categories number="0" parent="0"]`
you will display Category 1,2,3 and 4 only not all the products

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30085677)